# How to extend/patch an existing module or package?

Tags: python, locale, extend

I want to extend some locale-specific features of a python application named OpenERP. All I need is implementing a third party module.function that would be called every time OpenERP calls locale.setlocale() function without changing neither OpenERP nor locale module source code.

The only way I can imagine is provide a module named locale.py inside main application package dir, but It seems that is an unpythonic workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Look up [Monkey Patching](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch). It's not most elegant technique, but sometimes it's the only option.

In your case you can substitute your own function for `locale.setlocale()` which will do whatever you want. It would look something like that:

```
import locale

original_setlocale = locale.setlocale

def my_setlocale(category, locale=None):
    # Do anything you want
    # optionally call original function
    original_setlocale(category, locale)
```